# jQuery unobtrusive validation on composite html control

Tags: jquery, html, jquery-validate

I have the following control that represents Time:

```
<div id="xxx">
   <input type="text" name="xxx.hour"/>
   <input type="text" name="xxx.minute"/>
</div>
```

Because I want to add validation, I added:

```
<div id="xxx" data-val="true" data-val-time="Time no valid">
   <input type="text" name="xxx.hour"/>
   <input type="text" name="xxx.minute"/>
</div>
```

And I added the adapter and method:

```
$.validator.addMethod("time_method", function (val, el, params) {

    var elementId = $(el).attr('id');
    alert('id ' + elementId);
    var hour= $(el).children('input[name$=.hour]').val();
    var minute= $(el).children('input[name$=.minute]').val();

    return hour>= 0 && hour<24 && minute>=0 && minute<23;
});

$.validator.unobtrusive.adapters.add("time", {},
function (options) {
    options.rules["time_method"] = true;
    options.messages["time_method"] = options.message;
});
```

But the method "time_method" is never executed, I guess because jquery.validate only applies on input tags, am I right?

What would be the best way to do it?

**UPDATE:** I know it could be done in several ways, I'm just interested in the possibility of do it this way. I have simplify the problem to show a very small and silly example of what I'm trying to achieve.

Answer (score 2):

**demo:** https://so.lucafilosofi.com/jquery-unobstrusive-validation-on-composite-html-control

---

your code should look something like this:

```
$(function() {
    $.validator.addMethod('time_method',function(val, el) {
        var re,max;
        if (el.id == 'xxx_hour') {
            re = /^\d{1,2}$/;
            max = 24;
        }
        if (el.id == 'xxx_minute') {
            re = /^\d{2}$/;
            max = 59;
        }
        return re.test(val) && val >= 0 && val <= max;
    },
    'Time no valid');

    $("#xxx").validate({
        rules: {
            xxx_hour: 'time_method',
            xxx_minute: 'time_method',
        }
    });
});
```

your html something like:

```
<form id="xxx">  
 <input type="text" name="xxx_hour" id="xxx_hour" maxlength="2"/>
 <input type="text" name="xxx_minute" id="xxx_minute" maxlength="2"/>
</form>
```

Comment: I cannot change the HTML code. It is a component auto-generated by a framework.

Comment: @vtortola: the main problem with your original code is that inputs name should have applicable name xxx.hour is not a valid format, you can avoid the maxlength, but you should change id and name, can you change it via javascript at page load?

Answer (score 0):

Since the validation of hours and minutes are independent, you could just add separate validators to the two input fields.

Comment: True, the problem is that MVC3 applies the attributes on the top container, so is the DIV whom gets the "data-*" attributes.

Comment: Ah, @vtortola, you didn't mention MVC3 in the question.

Comment: Right, because the question is about how to perform validation on a DIV, it has nothing to do with MVC3 :D

Answer (score 0):

Why not use something like this: http://jsfiddle.net/3KCd4/2/

Comment: because the aim of this thing is about to write custom plumbing code for this specific case

Answer (score 0):

I would keep it simple. The separate messages for minutes and hours or separate inputs and additional adapters seem overcomplicated to me. All you need is just the good regex for time input. Regex validator adapter is already included in plugin.

```
<input data-val="true" data-val-regex="Time is not valid" data-val-regex-pattern="^([0-1][0-9]|[2][0-3]):([0-5][0-9])$"
        type="text" id="time" name="time" value="" />
```

Idea of applying regex to it is mine. Regex pattern was taken from [here](http://regexlib.com/REDetails.aspx?regexp_id=59).

That validation plugin (and most of validation plugins probably) depend on `input` element specific properties, that are `value` in first place, and then the supported events that validation can be triggered with. div supports nor the `value`, neither `onchange` or other events.

If the object to be validated is so complex, I would suggest to write that validation on server or just in form submit event, without those dynamic validations and error message show -ups.

Comment: the problem is that MVC3 applies the attributes on the top container, in this case, the DIV. Usually, this is done over inputs, so it is no problem, but I'm trying to come up with a custom control, and then the validation doesn't work on DIV :(

Comment: Forget about minutes and hours, that was just an example. What I would like to know, is how perform validation on a DIV :P

Comment: As far as i'm concerned, validation cannot be done on div. Why would you do input validation on the html element that has nothing to do with values? :). And more, do it on server side. It's not the absolute requirement to do every kind of validation on client

Comment: well, and why not? In fact, what the validation does is get the "data-*" attributes and call the adapter, it could work. It is not that the concept of an "UserControl" is something new, so I was expecting a little bit of flexibility here :( In my case it is a requirement, I thing I will have to work out it in another way.

Comment: What does validation do? It validates VALUE. div does not contain value, that's what i'm talking about. Inputs do contain value. There's nothing about flexibility, you are trying to do it wrong way. Another option, as suggested, is to use separate validation for each input. And by the way, why do you want to use exactly that validation plugin? You could simply write event handler for form submit and show the error message.

Answer (score 0):

Since keypress and change events bubble, you can use

```
//in $.ready
$('div#xxx').keypress(function(){
    //Do validation
}
```

Replace keypress with change if you want the validation to occur when the input element(s) lose focus.